# Chimneysweeping exhaust pipe for performance

Tags: exhaust

Hypothetically, I was wondering if chimneysweeping exhaust pipe, if I have easy access to entry points, as in maybe the catalytic converter manifold taken out, would improve the engine performance as in easier way for the exhaust out rather than chugging through a dirty pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line answer is: No.

Reasoning: Your engine should run relatively good with very little soot which would be the only deposit which can form inside the exhaust pipes. If the engine were outputting large amounts of soot, your cats would plug first. The amount of soot which *might* be in the tail pipes, is going to be negligible at worst, and thus not causing you a lick of difference if you tried to clean them.